# which namespace is used for dicomconvert class

Tags: c#, asp.net, dicom

which namespace is used for dicomconvert class in asp.net(C#)

Comment: there is no default libs in framework for dicom. You should use 3rd party libraries

Comment: how to use? and which 3rd party libs is good? do u have any link?

Comment: Where did you download the dicomconvert file from?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Grassroots DICOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/) library , or look in codeplex DICOM related [projects](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=DICOM&ac=8).
Also [ClearCanvas](http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/) is promising open source project